# PHP Error- filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given

Tags: php, runtime-error, user-input, sanitization, filter-input

I'm trying to create a form that stores details to a database, however, when I try to sanatize/validate the inputs I keep getting the following error

> filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given

My code is as follows, any help on how to sort this would be great!

```
$customer->EMAIL = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'EMAIL', 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL');
$customer->TITLE = 'TITLE';
$customer->FNAME = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FNAME', 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING');
$customer->LNAME = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'LNAME', 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING');
$customer->DOB = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'DOB', 'FILTER_VALIIDATE_DATE');
$customer->PHONE = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PHONE', 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING');
$customer->COUNTRY = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'COUNTRY', 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING');
$customer->STAFF_NUM = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'STAFF_NUM', 'FILTER_VALIDATE_INT');
$customer->SUBSCRIPTION = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SUBSCRIPTION', 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING');
$customer->PASSWORD = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PASSWORD', 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING');
```

Comment: `'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL'` is a __string__, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is a __constant__

Comment: I had it without the quotations before, but I kept getting **Notice: Use of undefined constant FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING - assumed 'FILTER_SANATIZE_STRING'**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use constants, not string representations of those constants. Also, check the spelling of `sanitize`, e.g.

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FNAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Thank you! The spelling errors were the problem!